# Type casting OutArgument in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How can I cast the return type of an OutArgument of an activity in Workflow Designer? I can only type the name of a workflow variable and can't do anything more as I can see.

I want to do something like I show on the image attached.

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific and explain where and why you need to do it. Because if you do need such a thing, my bet is that something's wrong from the start. You're trying to assign the result to what? And to use it where?

Comment: @Jota I am trying to assign a WebAPI result, which is a collection to a property in the activity. Since I can't specify the return type of an activity is a collection using the "Select Type" dialog on WF designer, I need to do a type cast and then assign it.

Comment: @Jota Yes, you're right. I've been silly :-) Selecting generic list for the return type and choosing the type of my class for the type parameter did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Expression Editor use VB syntax

```
DirectCast(YourArgument, YourType)
```

in your sample, type

```
DirectCast(argument, IList(Of String))
```

remove the assignation, it will be done automatically

Comment: Actually I'm using C# in the expression editors. Thanks for the help though.